# ¿Cómo puedo tener múltiples cajas con la misma distribución de GNU/LINUX con vagrant?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, nginx, vagrant

Descargué de la página **https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search** una caja con **ubuntu/xenial64** hasta ahí todo bien, pero lo que requiero es que pueda tener varias cajas con esa versión de ubuntu sin que se sobrescriban o reemplacen a la hora de ejecutar el comando de **vagrant up**.

Nativamente tengo la distribución de ubntu en mi pc y por consiguiente, al ejecutar el comando **vagrant up** dentro de la carpeta donde tengo mi archivo **Vagrantfile** empieza la descarga de la caja y se crea en la ruta de **.vagrant/box/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-xenial64**.

Lo que necesito es que yo pueda tener dos cajas con **ubuntu/xenial64** independientes, ya que en una necesito **LAMP** y en otra **LEMP**, pero con la misma distribución de GNU/LINUX.

Tengo dos carpetas, en una(en la que requiero **LEMP**) tengo un archivo **Vagrantfile** con la siguiente estructura:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.define "nginx_ubuntu" do |nginx_ubuntu|
  end
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
       vb.name = "nginx_ubuntu"
  end
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.synced_folder "htdocs", "/var/www/html"
end
```

y en otra carpeta (que es la que requiero **LAMP**) la tengo así:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.define "apache_ubuntu" do |apache_ubuntu|
  end
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
       vb.name = "apache_ubuntu"
  end
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.synced_folder "htdocs", "/var/www/html"
end
```

No trabajaría en ellas al mismo tiempo; por ejemplo, hoy trabajo en la máquina que tiene **LEMP** y mañana en la que tiene **LAMP**

En resumen:

¿Cómo puedo tener dos máquinas virtuales independientes con vagrant usando ubuntu/xenial64 para en una tener **LEMP** y en otra **LAMP**?

Gracias.

Comment: Problema solucionado...

Pude aprovisionar diferentes cajas con vagrant, cada una independiente para así poder manejar diferentes distribuciones de GNU/LINUX.